# Sort column by STIME in PS

Tags: linux, bash, ps

I am trying to develop a script will find the latest process that created by certain pts, for example pts/0. Then I need to print PID of this process.

```
    ps -ft $name
???
 ``
```

Answer (score 1):

`ps` offers to sort the returned list of processes by a field of your choice. In this case you'll sort by `etime` (execution time)..

Like this:

```
name="pts/2" # ... for example
ps -t "${name}" -o pid  --sort etime --no-header
  25624
   7856
```

To get only the most recent one, pipe to `head`:

```
ps -t "${name}" -o pid  --sort etime --no-header | head -n1
  25642
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out below script to get latest processes PID by pts

```
ps -ef | sort -k5r | grep pts | awk '{print $6}' | sort -u | grep -v "?" | while read pts; do
      echo "pts id $pts"
      ps -ft $pts
      echo "==================="
      done
```